# how to get request's xml structure in server file via nusoap

Tags: php, xml, web-services, nusoap

I am beginner to nusoap and xml and I am trying to create a endpoint url for a request in defined structure. I have created a dummy soap_server and soap_client using nusoap. Following is code for soap_client:

soap_client.php:

```
 <?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/projects/NuSOAP/zip_code_server.php");
$error = $client->getError();
if ($error) {
    echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}
//Use basic authentication method
$client->setCredentials("codezone4", "123", "basic");
$result = "";

if ($client) {
    $result = $client->call("OTA_HotelAvailRQ", array("hotel_code" => "hotel1"));
}
if ($client->fault) {
    echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
} else {
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    } else {
    //echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
    echo "<h2>zip code</h2><pre>";
    echo $result;
    echo "</pre>";
  }
}
```

In soap_server.php I have returned custom xml using below code:

```
<?php

require_once 'lib/nusoap.php';
function doAuthenticate() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) and isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))     {
        if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == "codezone4" && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == "123")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}


function OTA_HotelAvailRQ($hotel_code_array) {
    //Can query database and any other complex operation
   if (!doAuthenticate()){
        return "Invalid username or password";
    }
    //echo '<pre>';print_r($hotel_code_array);die;
    if(is_array($hotel_code_array)){
        $hotel_code=$hotel_code_array['AvailRequestSegment']['HotelSearchCriteria']['Criterion']['HotelRef']['HotelCode'];
    }else{
        $hotel_code=$hotel_code_array;
    }
    if ($hotel_code == "hotel1") {
        global $server;
        $server->methodreturnisliteralxml = true;
        return '
            <abc><xyz></xyz></abc>';
    }else {
            return '<Errors>

          </Errors>';
    }
}

$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("hotelroomslist", "urn:hotelroomslist");

//Register web service function so that clients can access
$server->register("OTA_HotelAvailRQ",
    array("hotel_code_array" => "xsd:string"),
    array("return" => "xsd:int"),
    "hotelroomslist",
    "hotelroomslist#OTA_HotelAvailRQ",
    "rpc",
    "encoded",
    "Retrieve zip code for a given area");

$POST_DATA = isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'])?      $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] : '';
$server->service($POST_DATA);
?>
```

Here In my xml structure there are no security headers, and I want to change structure of this request, how can I do this. Below is my xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns5407:OTA_HotelAvailRQ xmlns:ns5407="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <hotel_code xsi:type="xsd:string">hotel1</hotel_code>                                    </ns5407:OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.